# Rails / Paperclip: file_field not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm attempting to use PaperClip and have been following the quick start found on their GitHub page.

I've got the gem install, model & controller set up, and in the view I have:

```
<% form_for @account, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    <% end %>
```

But nothing displays when the page renders. I've stripped out all CSS to ensure that isn't an issue, but still not luck. Any thoughts on why the file picker isn't displaying?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what version of Rails you are using but I think you forgot the equals sign in the form helper, try:

```
<%= form_for @account, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @user464180 This. `<%= form_for` instead of `<% form_for` is the important part. If you view the source, you'll find that not even the `<form>` tags are being rendered unless you use `<%=`.